# How to prevent the application from closing when clicking the close button in a C# windows app?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

I am coding a Windows form based application in C#.

When I click on the `red cross(x)` on the top right corner of the windows it should not stop the execution of the program. It should instead go to next part of the program.  What do I need to do in order to have my program behave this way?

Comment: a sample of code please?

Comment: "it does not stops the execution" what execution - do you mean close the window, or do you mean shut down a task you're running in a background thread too?

Comment: What is with the down-voting here? If a question is not clear, it's considerate to ask for further details, rather than blindly down-voting.

Comment: @MusiGenesis - 4 people requested additional information.  The author has not replied, the question is not clear, this is a bad question IMO.

Comment: @Ramhound 4 of the downvotes were within 5 minutes of the thread being posted.  That's not providing sufficient time for the OP to respond to clarifying questions.  If the OP hasn't responded after 1/2 to 1 hour, then downvoting would be appropriate in my eyes.

Comment: The voting here raises an interesting question - while it certainly shouldn't be downvoted into oblivion, should it be upvoted when it's clearly -not- a useful, clear question that shows research effort?

Comment: @J.Steen That assumes that not voting at all isn't a valid option.

Comment: @Servy Obviously thousands of people haven't voted, but it still makes me curious about 'correct' behaviour. =)

Comment: Was a sample of the code really necessary ? The question has been answered without the code. So it seems the downvotes were unnecessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the form closing event to cancel the closing of the form. In the designer click the lighting symbol in the properties and double click the form closing entry. This should make the code for you. It should make a function a bit like this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

You need to add the `e.Cancel` that will stop the form closing

Comment: I think the OP actually wants the _opposite_ of this functionality. =D

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to C#. I have tried the above and it seems code never goes to this method. Am I suppose to code something in initialize() ???

Comment: I am getting an error says e.cancel ==== does not have definition for cancel.

Comment: Sorry, the grammar of your question threw me a little. If you want to exit the application then the answer by James should suffice. The code I provided can be used to stop the program from exiting.

Comment: Also the case of the 'Cancel' is important. Make sure it is caps-case

Comment: ... or OP meant the exact opposite of what he/she was asking. Hard to tell, really.

Comment: I revised the question title & deleted my answer and sacrificed my precious rep! In the context of the revised question, this is the correct answer :)